# Is there a command that ties information to the user?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Let me rephrase the question : Is there a command that has different values for different users but uses the same variable/command?

So i'm trying to create a game bot on discord. I'm currently trying to make the bank part where if they type 'prefix bal' it shows their bank balance. Instead of creating a new variable for every single user, is there a way to tie this information to the user so that when the user uses the command, the info is taken from the user and then shows it?

This is could sound complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org)? It contains a ton of information on the specific data you can get for any given user. You might have been able to answer this question yourself simply by going to that website, and researching the `User` or `GuildMember` objects.

In our case, we can simply use the users' IDs. After all, by definition IDs are supposed to be used for identification. All users have a unique ID, and that is exactly the type of unique variable you are looking for.

As for tying the bank balance with the user ID, you simply need simple data structure(s) that can tie a key to a value. The easiest way to do so is to use a dictionary data structure, which we can achieve easily with Javascript's object notation:

```
var balances = {
    "UserID_1": 50,
    "UserID_2": 178
}

//Format is
//"ID": balance
```

When you want to access the balance of a specific user:

```
var userBal = balances[message.author.id];
```

When you want to set/insert the user's balance:

```
balances[message.author.id] = 190;
//'190' is just an example balance
```

Of course, if you want your users' bank balance data to persist even after your bot eventually restarts, you'll need to store the `balances` object in a JSON file instead of simply saving it to a variable. As for how you do that, that is an entirely different question altogether and it is a question that has been answered on this website many times before (you should easily find the solution). If you want an example of saving your data in a JSON file, [this](https://github.com/Cannicide/scav-bot/blob/master/evg.js) is how I do it in my own discord bots.

Relevant resources:
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=id

Comment: I tried using Collections but its not working

Comment: Collections? This answer isn't using Collections, did you try what I described in this answer?

Comment: im trying to make the bot public, so rather than adding the user id manually, i made a collection and if the author isnt there in the collection, it will add the user and a value.

Btw i fixed it after like 3 hours